# Javascript - check/uncheck checkbox after summing different inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a ‘parent’ `<div>`, and ‘child’ divs which are shown after clicking parent `<div>`.
All divs have `<checkboxes>` and `<input>` to put quantity.

Parent `<checkbox>` checks when at least one child `<checkbox>` is checked.

When child `<checkbox>` is checked/unchecked the quantity in `<input>` is automatically changed into ‘1’ or ‘’.

Parent quantity `<input>` is disabled and it is supposed to show the sum of all children quantities.

I have two problems.

First, the summing script works fine when you enter the quantity yourself, however when the quantity appears/disappears itself (after checking/unchecking the child `<checkbox>`) the summing script does not react on such change.

Secondly I wasn’t able to uncheck the parent `<checkbox>` when all child checkboxes are unchecked. 
However I’m assuming if the summing script will start working properly I will be able to bind the parent `<checkbox>` with the sum `(if (sum> 0){ $('#checkbox0').prop('checked', true);}else{$('#checkbox0').prop('checked', false);}`

Html:

```
    <div class="divCell" id="click1">
    <div class="checkbox_div" style='pointer-events:none;'>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox0">
    </div>   
    <div class="div_name_divcell">Parent - click to open</div>
    <div class="div_quantity_divcell">
    <input type="text" name="parent_1" class="quantity_class_parent_1" id="quantity_parent_1" size="1" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)" disabled="disabled">
   </div>
</div>
<div id="hidden1" style="display: none;">
 <div class="divCell" id="child_click1">
    <div class="checkbox_div">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
    </div>   
    <div class="div_name_divcell">Child1</div>
    <div class="div_quantity_divcell">
      <input type="text" name="child_1" class="quantity_class_child" id="quantity_child_1" size="1" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)">
   </div>
 </div>

  <div class="divCell" id="child_click2">
    <div class="checkbox_div">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
    </div>   
    <div class="div_name_divcell">Child2</div>
    <div class="div_quantity_divcell">
      <input type="text" name="child_1" class="quantity_class_child" id="quantity_child_2" size="1" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.divCell {width: 500px;height: 35px;margin: 2px 0;display: inline-block;background-color: #D4F78F;}
.div_quantity_divcell{float:right; padding:9px 1px 0 0}
.checkbox_div {width: 25px;position: relative;margin: 5px;float: left;}
.div_name_divcell {line-height: 35px;width: auto;float: left;}
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#checkbox1').click(function() {
        if(this.checked){     
            $('#checkbox0').prop('checked', this.checked); 
            $('#quantity_child_1').val('1')     
        }else{ 
            $('#quantity_child_1').val('')
        //$('#checkbox0').prop('checked', false);
        }});
        $('#quantity_child_1').keyup(function(){
            $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', this.value > 0);
        $('#checkbox0').prop('checked', true);
        })
      //second child
        $('#checkbox2').click(function() {
        if(this.checked){     
            $('#checkbox0').prop('checked', this.checked); 
            $('#quantity_child_2').val('1')     
        }else{ 
            $('#quantity_child_2').val('') 
        //$('#checkbox0').prop('checked', false);
        }});
        $('#quantity_child_2').keyup(function(){
            $('#checkbox2').prop('checked', this.value > 0);
        $('#checkbox0').prop('checked', true);
        })
    });
    // suming script

    $(document).on('change', '.quantity_class_child', function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $('.quantity_class_child').each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
        });

        $('#quantity_parent_1').val(sum);
    });

//opening script
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#click1').click(function() {
        if ($('#hidden1').is(':hidden')) {
       $('#hidden1').show(500);
    } else {
       $('#hidden1').hide(500);
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mamzj4tw/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Here are the things that you can do to achieve,

*First, the summing script works fine when you enter the quantity yourself, however when the quantity appears/disappears itself (after checking/unchecking the child ) the summing script does not react on such change.*

The thing is change event will not be triggered if you are setting/changing the value from the javascript. For this you can manually call the change event to trigger the effect. Or, Create a separate function for summation calculation and call it on uncheck event of the checkbox.

eg.

**Either**

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#checkbox0').prop('checked', this.checked);
      $('#quantity_child_1').val('1')
    } else {
      $('#quantity_child_1').val('')
      $(".quantity_class_child").trigger("change");
        //$('#checkbox0').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
```

**OR**

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#checkbox0').prop('checked', this.checked);
      $('#quantity_child_1').val('1')
    } else {
      $('#quantity_child_1').val('');
        summation();
    }
  });

function summation(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('.quantity_class_child').each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $('#quantity_parent_1').val(sum);
 }
```

Now for the second part,

*Secondly I wasn’t able to uncheck the parent  when all child checkboxes are unchecked.*

Just check the length of the checked input box during the summation process and uncheck it if the the length is zero.

Hope this help you cause.

Answer (score 2):

This is an updated version of your version

https://jsfiddle.net/mamzj4tw/13/

It uses `each()` to better (and clean) add actions to inputs.

You can create your custom events like `do-sum` and fire when you want.
In this case I defined that the sum is executed when
`$(document).trigger('do-sum');`
fires do-sum event.

and I've set a listener that executes your routine:

`$(document).on('do-sum', function(){
    var sum = 0;
        $('.quantity_class_child.active').each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val();
        });
        $('#quantity_parent_1').val(sum);
        var parentChecked = false;
    $('#hidden1 input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, e){
            if($(e).is(':checked')) {
        parentChecked = true;
      }
    });
    $('#checkbox0').prop('checked', parentChecked);
});`

I also use class `active` to set valid inputs (and quick sum them).

PS you don't need `event.preventDefault();` after document ready event.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was a bit to complicated, so i have rewritten what you tried to archive ( without the css part).  [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kkhbuoq2/)

three little html div's

```
<div class="parent" id="parent">
 <span class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" name="parent" value="">
  <label for parent>parent - click to open</label>
  <input type="text" name="sum">
 </span> 
</div>
<div class="child" id="child1">
 <span class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inputCheckbox" name="child1" value="child1">
  <input type="text" class="inputSum" name="sum1">
 </span> 
</div>
<div class="child" id="child2">
 <span class="input">
  <input type="checkbox" class="inputCheckbox" name="child2" value="child2">
  <input type="text" class="inputSum" name="sum2">
 </span> 
</div>
```

and a bit of jquery

```
$('.child').hide(); 
// check if parent checkbox is checked

$('input[name="parent"]').click ( function () { 
  if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) $('.child').show(); else $('.child').hide();
})

// check if childcheckbox is checked , if true trigger keyup and sum
$('.inputCheckbox').on ( 'change', function () {  
 if ( $(this).is(':checked') )  $(this).next().val('1').keyup();
// if not , trigger parent
 if ( ! $('.inputCheckbox').is(':checked')  ) $('input[name="parent"]').click ();  
})
// check if value is entered and sum it on keyup
$('.inputSum').on('keyup', function () {  
 var sum = 0;
 $('.inputSum').each ( function () { sum +=  ( $(this).val() - 0)   })
 $('input[name="sum"]').val(sum)
})
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can add new elements https://jsfiddle.net/mamzj4tw/34/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.drop-down #checkbox').on('change',function(){
        $(this).closest('.divCell').find('#quantity_child')
        .val(this.checked ? 1:'').trigger('keyup');
    });

    $(document).on('keyup click', '.quantity_class_child', function(){
        $(this).closest('.divCell').find('#checkbox').prop("checked",+$(this).val());
        var sum = 0;
        $('.quantity_class_child').each(function(){sum += +$(this).val()});
        $('#quantity_parent_1').val(sum ||'');
        $('#checkbox0').prop("checked", sum);
    });

    $('#click1').click(function() { $('#hidden1').toggle(500); });
});
```